# Make a SELECT WHERE query of a custom field unique for each user ID

Tags: php, wordpress, select

I'm using MemberMouse for Wordpress to handle reoccurring subscriptions and I need to add a members directory (MemberMouse do not offer this) that queries MemberMouse for the info. About a dozen fields on the MemberMouse signup form are custom fields, a mixture of text and drop downs, plus one checkbox that lets the user decide if they want to appear in the directory or not.

My PHP knowledge is limited but so far I have written a small test item just to make sure I can return a result from the MemberMouse custom field and so far I have this:

```
    global $wpdb;
    $args = array(
        'role'    => 'paid-member',
        'orderby' => 'user_nicename',
        'order'   => 'DSC'
    );
    $users = get_users( $args );

    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ( $users as $user ) {  

    $is_in_database = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT value FROM mm_custom_field_data WHERE custom_field_id = '1' " );

    echo '<li>' . esc_html( $user->display_name ) . ' [' . esc_html( $user->user_email ) . ']</li>';

    echo 'Custom Field Data: '.$is_in_database.' </br></br>';

    }
    echo '</ul>';
```

This sort of works, it lists the members name and email, but where I pull the data from the custom field, it shows the first value in the database for all users rather than the unique value that is in this field for each user. How do I make it check each USER ID separately and get the custom value for that user?

I have about 8 or so of these 'SELECT' queries to add for each person.

Thank-you

Answer (score 0):

You are fetching always the same data with:

```
$is_in_database = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT value FROM mm_custom_field_data WHERE custom_field_id = '1' " );
```

If you want to return a custom field data based on the user displayed, you need to do a `SELECT` filtered by the ID of the user. Something like that should do the trick:

```
$is_in_database = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare(
    "
        SELECT value
        FROM mm_custom_field_data
        WHERE user_id = %d
    ",
    $user->ID
));
```

I don't know `mm_custom_field_data` table structure, but I suppose that the column containing the ID of the user is `user_id`. You should check, just to be safe.